# What is 'each' in the jQuery $.each looping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to access the data in a table row. The data may be in a `<td>` tag, or as text in an input, or as a checkbox in an input, or a button.

As a demonstration I have a small table:-

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td dir="ltr" id="test1" class="tLine" nowrap>Column One</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked>Check Box.</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="clicked">Update</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The Javascript is :-

```
<script>
    $(".clicked").click(function() {
        var $row = $(this).closest("tr");       // Finds the closest row <tr> 
        var $tds = $row.find("td");             // Finds all children <td> elements
        $.each($tds, function() {               // Visits every single <td> element
           console.log($(this).text());        // Prints out the text within the <td>
         });
        console.log($tds[0].tagName); // 'TD'
        console.log($tds[1].tagName); // 'TD'
        $.each($tds, function(index, value) { // Visits every single <td> element
           console.log($tds[index].tagName); // 'TD'
           console.log($(this).tagName);  // Undefined
           console.log($(each).tagName);  // Fails
         });
    });
</script>
```

What exactly is the each in the 2nd loop and how do I use it?
Why is the $(this).tagName undefined?

Once I get the TD element I can check what the content is by looking at children...

I am also looking at javascript/jquery table options like SlickGred, jsgrid and DataTables, but would like to understand the code above first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What exactly is the each in the 2nd loop and how do I use it?

If you mean the one element in the collection it is `value`, the second parameter in your callback function. But with `$.each` you can also do this with `this`.

> Why is the $(this).tagName undefined?

Because `$(this)` instantiates a jQuery object, and there is no `tagName` property in a jQuery object. You could do `this.tagName`, or `value.tagName`.

The reason why `$tds[0].tagName` works is that although `$tds` is a jQuery object, it is also an "array-like" object because all the individual element that are wrapped in it are placed in properties/indices like `'0'`, `'1'` etc. So when you do `$tds[0]`, you get the actual element and it has the `tagName` property.

Answer (score 2):

`$(this)` returns a jQuery object. `this` is a `DOMElement`.

Comment: I didn't find this explained the situation,